# vba Macro to Consolidate Data from Different Workbooks into One Workbook

Tags: vba

I need a macro that gathers information from 3 different workbooks and consolidates it on one tab in a 4th workbook.

For each file, the number of columns is the same, but the number of rows differs. What I need to macro to do is to take the data + column headings from the first of the 3 source files and paste them into the destination file. Then, for each subsequent source file, I need the macro to paste just the data (no column headings) starting in the row immediately below.

Also the destination file is in a different folder than the source files. One more thing I will be adding new files in the future so the number of source file might be greater. So below are just examples of names for people to help me with the code, and I can go in and change the details afterward.

Here are the details:

1) Each source file has the data I need to copy in columns A:I.
 2) In each source file, the column headings are in row 1, with the data beginning in row 2.
 3) In each source file, the data that I need to copy is in the "Child File_NCANDS" tab.
 4) The folder where the 3 source files are located is titled "Testing Macro"
 5) In the destination file, the data will be copied and pasted into the "Child File_NCANDS" tab.
 6) The destination file is titled "TA Call Notes_Compiled_TEST.xls"

Here is the code I came up with so far:

```
Sub TA_Call_Notes_Compiled()
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Dim i As Long, lCurrRow As Long, lRow As Long, n As Long
  Dim wb As Workbook, ans As VbMsgBoxResult

  For i = 1 To 3 Step 1

' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Open up Source Workbook
' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "N:\2012-2015 contract\State Data Submission_Validation_Communication\Technical Assistance\TA Calls 2018\Testing Macro" & i & ".xlsx")
If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
  Err.Clear

  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ' Source Workbook was not found using SourceX.xls format, try Source X.xls format
  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "N:\2012-2015 contract\State Data Submission_Validation_Communication\Technical Assistance\TA Calls 2018\Testing Macro" & i & ".xls")
  If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
    Err.Clear

    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' No source workbook found, advise user.
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ans = MsgBox("Could not find Source " & i & " Workbook." & vbNewLine & "Do you wis" & _
                 "h to continue?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Error")
    If ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    GoTo NextI
  End If
End If

' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Source book was found, data to use is on Data Output.
' -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
With wb.Sheets("Child File_NCANDS")
  If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
    Err.Clear

    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' No Data Output tab found, advise user.
    ' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ans = MsgBox("Could not find Source " & i & " Workbook's 'Data Output' tab." & _
                 vbNewLine & "Do you wish to continue?", vbInformation + vbYesNo, "Error")
    If ans = vbNo Then
      wb.Close False
      Exit Sub
    End If
    GoTo NextI
  End If

  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ' Ensure we add headers.
  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  If i = 1 Then
    lRow = 1
  Else
    lRow = 2
  End If

  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ' We are assuming the value in column A will be filled and there is no breaks until the
  ' end of our entries.  If this is not the case additional code will be needed to
  ' determine the end of our entries.
  ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Do Until .Range("A:I" & lRow).Value = vbNullString
    lCurrRow = lCurrRow + 1
    For n = 0 To 3 Step 1
      Sheets("Child File_NCANDS").Range("A:I" & lCurrRow).Offset(ColumnOffset:=n).Value = .Range("A:I" & lRow).Offset(ColumnOffset:=n).Value
    Next n
    lRow = lRow + 1
  Loop
End With
NextI:
wb.Close False
Next i
Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just have your file already contain the headers so you do not have to code for it? If they are constant, having a macro do it seems like over kill. It's a manual step that only has to be done once

Comment: yes my source files contain headers as well as the destination file. I am getting an error from my code saying it could not find source files

Comment: Are you open to using a file dialogue instead? I find those to be better

Comment: Yes I am open to using it if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, this assumes the header on the destination sheet already exists. It doesn't make sense to code for it when you only have to add the header to your destination sheet once.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Child File_NCANDS")
Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim Currentbook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer, LRow As Long, wbLRow As Long
Dim Import As Range

'Opens File Dialog to Select Which Files You Want to Consolidate
Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With IndvFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Show
End With

If IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub 'If no files are selected, Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = 1 To IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count 'Loop for selected files
        Set Currentbook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(i))
            With Currentbook.Sheets("Child File_NCANDS")
                LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Last Row of Import Sheet
                wbLRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row 'Last Row of Destination Sheet
                    Set Import = .Range("A2:I" & LRow)
                    Import.Copy
                    ws.Range("A" & wbLRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        Currentbook.Close False
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Child File_NCANDS")                                                                                              gives me an error

Comment: the code ran without error but for some reason the destination tab grabs only the first row of data of the first two source files

Comment: Lrow was calculated right. I tried it again and it worked. Thanks

Comment: We don't do this for free. The cost is validating solutions *when they work* :)

Comment: If want to do the same for other tabs what should I do. Just repeat the same code with a different destination sheet or loop through the tabs inside the current code. Let me know if that make sense.

Comment: In response to your question for extending this to other sheets - You can either create a sheet loop inside this macro (loop will be nested inside file loop) or you can create a copy of this macro and adjust the sheet names as needed.

Comment: Do you know how to create a sheet loop inside this macro? The tabs from my source files have the same name as my destination file. I Have a total of 7 tabs.

Comment: I do but this needs to be a new question since this was not your original ask. If questions were allowed to continuously evolve, no question would ever truly be answered. Posting a new question will also help future readers with your problem and preserve this solution for readers with this problem. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: In summary, post a new question with this code. Clearly explain what you need modified about it in your question. I or someone else will be able to assist. Although, you should make a honest effort to solve this on your own first. There are plenty of questions about your ask that already exist with working solutions